# Trying to implement a list to select Records, and email attachments, could use some pointers!

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-email-service

I recently just started working with Salesforce and Apex/VisualForce and was attempting to implement a page to email out the attachments of a Service Contract, however I seem to be stumbling with the best way to select multiple Service Contracts from a list to email, I believe my controller is all set to go but I haven't figured out a way to make a list of my service contracts, I've attempted to do so with selectlists, and enhancedlists, but I didn't get very far with those, any ideas?

My Visual Force Page:

[image: Page]

My Apex Controller:

```
public class SendEmailWithAttachment{

    public String subject;

    public String body;

    public String[]toAddresses { get; set; }

    public String[]ccAddresses { get; set; }

    public ServiceContract[] serv { get; set; }

    public void sendAttachment(/*String[] toAddresses, String[] ccAddresses, ServiceContract serv */) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);   // set the to address
        mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);   //set the cc address
        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Files Attached');
        //mail.setWhatId(c.Id);// Set email file attachments
        for (integer i = 0; serv.size() > i; i++) {
            mail.setSubject(serv[i].Name + 'Attachments');
            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
            for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :serv[i].Id]){  // Add to attachment file list  
                Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment(); 
                efa.setFileName(a.Name);
                efa.setBody(a.Body);
                fileAttachments.add(efa);
            }
            mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);// Send email
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard pattern for presenting a list of objects that can be selected is this [Wrapper Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) pattern.

In your case it would be the `ServiceContract` object that you wrap, and the list you present would be queried by your controller. The user can then choose one or more of these via the checkbox and the `sendAttachment` method would only do the send for the checked items.